# Encrypted Code Blocks in IDE

Tags: java, c#, encryption, ide

In my company, I saw a project(c# desktop application) that has encrypted code blocks.That is to say, as long as I open the project in Visual Studio, encrypted code blocks are shown.
I tried to decode what have written but couldn't.
Could anyone tell me how is this possible or Is there a way to encrpyt your codes?

Cheers,

Comment: You need to find a way to trace the method that was used to encrypt the data in the first place. There are literally trillions of ways it could have been encrypted. As you stated, it is for the company you work for, so I guess it still has to be on your company's server repositories. I suggest looking first at C# code files that handle security.

Comment: Source codes are shown same as in IDe when I check the files.And no security trace I have met.That just encrypted code blocks we have.